# Query hierarchical items in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

We have a table in house which as hierarchical data in the following format. `Items` is the parent table with list of items. But, the relationship between items is maintained in `std_item_rel` table

**Constraints:**

- `items.item_id(PK) = std_item_rel.std_item_down(PK)(FK)`
- `items.item_id_sd(PK) = std_item_rel.item_id_sd_dwn(PK)(FK)`
- `std_item_rel.std_item_up  (fk)  to std_item_rel.std_item_dwn`
- `std_item_rel.item_id_sd_up  (fk)  to std_item_rel.item_id_sd_dwn`

How do I write a query to get all the subordinate values for item `123` from below sample schema?

**items**

```
item_id | item_id_sd|  item_desc
----------------------------
123     |  A        |  Some description
```

**std_item_rel**

```
std_item_dwn | item_id_sd_dwn | item_id_sd_up | std_item_up 
------------------------------------------------------------
123          |   A            |     null      | null
125          |   C            |     A         | 123
129          |   C            |     C         | 125
```

---

**Update:**
Error I got was:

```
ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data
01436. 00000 -  "CONNECT BY loop in user data"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Fixed it by adding `nocycle` param in the `connect by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONNECT BY` should allow for rather simple solutions, here:

```
SELECT     std_item_down
FROM       std_item_rel
CONNECT BY std_item_up = PRIOR std_item_down
START WITH std_item_down = 123
```

[See also this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/567dc/2)

Comment: What if I have to join multiple columns? does it have same syntax? (I hid other columns of the PK to keep it simple)

Comment: I cannot guess your actual problem :-) The syntax is essentially the same, but `CONNECT BY` is often not very intuitive. So maybe you add some additional info to your question?

Comment: Modified to have more columns.. i've tried it in sql developer, it seems to show me some compilation errors with connect by key word.. we use oracle 10g btwn

Comment: @Zeus: if you tried something and get an error, you should also include that code **and** the *exact* error message in your modified question.